# Javascript - call the first level object from a sub object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i have problem to call the super object from a sub object.

dn is undefined if you remove the //comment

http://jsfiddle.net/HsZp6/2/

```
dn =
{
    documentTags:
    {
        elements: html.find('*'),
        description: 'Document tags',

        //amount: dn.documentTags.elements.length + 1,

        // returns dn is undefined
        amountNinja: 400,
        amountTrainee: 1500,
        amountNovice: 3000
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare a json object in which amount is just another property. Before the object is defined you are trying to use it which is not at all possible.

Try this

```
dn =
{
    documentTags:
    {
        elements: html.find('*'),
        description: 'Document tags',

        //amount: dn.documentTags.elements.length + 1,

        // returns dn is undefined
        amountNinja: 400,
        amountTrainee: 1500,
        amountNovice: 3000
    }
};

dn.amount = dn.documentTags.elements.length + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var elements = html.find('*');
dn =
{
    documentTags:
    {
        elements: elements,
        description: 'Document tags',

        amount: elements.length + 1,

        // returns dn is undefined
        amountNinja: 400,
        amountTrainee: 1500,
        amountNovice: 3000
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

look for this example

```
function addChild(ob, childName, childOb)
{
ob[childName] = childOb;
childOb.parent = ob;
}

var life= {
    mameAndDestroy : function(group){ },
    kiss : function(group){ }
};

addChild(life, 'users', {
guys : function(){ this.parent.mameAndDestroy(this.girls); },
girls : function(){ this.parent.kiss(this.boys); },
});
```